# Swift 4 UICollectionView detect end of scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, swift4

I have an `Horizontal` `UICollectionView` on my app and I want to load more data when the user reaches the end (or nearly to the end) of UICollectionView while dragging on the left.

I'm using Swift 4. I found some Swift 3 solutions but they do not work for me.

My current code is:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.videoViewModel.images.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imgImage.image = self.videoViewModel.images[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    updateVideo(data: self.videoViewModel.relatedVideos[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: How many visible cells are there ?

Comment: loading data from api?

Comment: 10, First I load 10 and then I need to append 10 again every time scrollbar reaches at some point at the end. @McDonal_11

Comment: yes I am loading data from api @ivarun

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may use cellForItem or willDisplayItem methods of collection view. Check if the last cell is being displayed, and load your data. For example:

Swift:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if (indexPath.row == dataSource.count - 1 ) { //it's your last cell
       //Load more data & reload your collection view
     }
}
```

Objective-C:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == dataSource.count - 1 ) { //it's your last cell
       //Load more data & reload your collection view

    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if it didn't help in your case.

Comment: yes, exactly. But make sure to handle edge cases properly :)

Comment: and you may do the same thing in cellForItem as well

Comment: for some reason in cellForItem it fires earlier. I will leave it as you suggested. Sorry what do you mean by edge cases?

Comment: because cell for item is called little earlier even before displaying the cell. forexample, if you've cell#2,3,4,5 visible on the screen, cellForItem will be called even for cell#6 and may be 7 as well.. just to optimize things you know. Hope it makes sense

Comment: By edge cases i mean, if dataSource is empty, or if you've no more data to load etc. Otherwise, you'll always be sending API call even if you've already loaded all the data.

Comment: Yes of course I will sort it out, put some boolean there or sth. Thanks.

Comment: please accept if the answer was helpful & you are not waiting for more answers!

Comment: if you could have waited 1 more sec :p

Answer (score 10):

Implement method `scrollViewDidScroll` of `UIScrollViewDelegate`:

```
var isLoading: Bool = false

 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let contentOffsetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    if contentOffsetX >= (scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.bounds.width) - 20 /* Needed offset */ {
        guard !self.isLoading else { return }
        self.isLoading = true
        // load more data
        // than set self.isLoading to false when new data is loaded
    }
}
```

Comment: I put this method on my ViewController and I also implemented UIScrollViewDelegate but nothing is happening. You can check my code at https://gitlab.com/rexhin/ios-kida.git

Comment: now it fires but multiple times like 10 or 20 if i go to the end.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Did you set `isLoading = false` when data is loaded?

Comment: sorry i forgot that let my try

Comment: still not good. first it fires like 20 times than when i go to the end it fires again multiple times

Comment: Are you set `isLoading = false` on main thread? Like this:
`DispatchQueue.main.async { self.isLoading = false }`

Comment: I can not do that because I'm using a service for that which is in another file rather than ViewController. I did it like this.  `func related(videoName: String) {
        videoViewModel.related(videoName: videoName) { (result: VideoViewModel.Related) in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                
            case .success( _):
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                self.isLoading = false
            }
        }
    } `

This is the function I call to load data.

Comment: This works in the test project. Are you sure you did everything right? Maybe you didn't remove the code from other answer? `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {...}`

Comment: this answer is better than the one on top, because if u have a collection view with different number of elements in each section/row the previous answer wont work. good job ilya

Comment: Note: Works perfectly if you set self.collectionView.bounces = false... Otherwise, upon scrolling to the bottom, the collection view will bounce and another cell that's not last will display

Answer (score 1):

Take one bool variable and one integer variable for page number like this:

```
var isDataLoading = false
var pageCount:Int = 1 // Pass this page number in your api
```

in cellForItemAt method add below code:

```
if !isDataLoading && indexPath.row == videoViewModel.count - 1 {
            isDataLoading = true
            pageCount += 1
// add you api call code here with pageCount
        }
```

once you get your data from api set isDataLoading bool to false like below:

```
self.isDataLoading = false
```

Comment: Thanks but i was interested more in detecting the end of scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

**This is simple login which will go down to last index...!!!**

```
func ScrollEnd() {
          let lastSectionIndex = (self.collectionView?.numberOfSections)! - 1
         let lastItemIndex = (self.collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: lastSectionIndex)) - 1
           let index =  IndexPath(item: lastItemIndex, section: lastSectionIndex)
           if messages.count != 0{
               self.collectionView!.scrollToItem(at: index, at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.bottom, animated: false)
           }    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your collectionView willDisplayCell delegate

```
if (indexPath.row == dataSource.count - 1 ) {
 //it's your last cell

//Load more data & reload your collection view
  }
```