# Scrolling CollectionView to left after ending should open another View Controller & same functionality on right end

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a collection view in which 4-5 images are there & its scrolling direction is horizontal. I want to push to a view controller after the end of scrolling of both the side (i.e) left & right. If the user is on the most left image of collection view & trying to swipe towards the right again then it should push to a new View Controller & same on the right side.
**I've tried this so far:-**

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in self.qrCodeCollctionView.visibleCells{
        let indexPaths = self.qrCodeCollctionView.indexPath(for: cell)

        if indexPaths!.row == 0{
            var cellInsets = UIEdgeInsets()
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                cellInsets = cell.safeAreaInsets
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
            print(cellInsets)
        }
    }
}
```

Answers on [Swift 4 UICollectionView detect end of scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705430/swift-4-uicollectionview-detect-end-of-scrolling) are not according my required functionality.

Comment: Post some code what u have tried. It will be useful to our SO followers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705430/swift-4-uicollectionview-detect-end-of-scrolling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift 4 UICollectionView detect end of scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705430/swift-4-uicollectionview-detect-end-of-scrolling)

Comment: @Manikandan No, that's why I'm seeking another way to solve it.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it in this way:-

```
    func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       let contentOffsetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x

       for cell in self.qrCodeCollctionView.visibleCells {
           let indexPath = self.qrCodeCollctionView.indexPath(for: cell)

           if indexPath?.row == 0{
               if contentOffsetX < -50{
                   let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:    nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as!    MyViewController
                   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
               }
           }
           else if indexPath?.row == (self.qrCodeDataArray.count - 1){
               if contentOffsetX > (scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.bounds.width) - 20{
                   print("over right")
                   self.scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(self.qrCodeCollctionView)
                   let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as! MyViewController
                   let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

                   vc.ContactFromVC = self.currentContact
                   vc.currentIndexVC = self.currentIndex
                   vc.delegateContact = self
                   self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
               }
           }
       }

}
```