# Cant get correct indexPath of collectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, indexpath

**EDIT:**
I try to get a correct indexPath of a current cell in a collectionView.

The project is simple: an album of photos and a label with a text. Text in label should be the current indexPath.

Concerning photos - everything is ok. Problem is with indexPath parameter in a label.

First right swipe changes indexPath for + 2 instead of +1: from [0,0] to [0,2] - instead of [0,1]. Right swipes that have been made after this work correctly.
But first left swipe changes the value of indexPath for -3. For example, if indexPath was [0,6] - the first left swipe will change it to [0, 3].

I have made a 10-sec video, representing a problem: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Qxqr_Q9SDJ8
The buttons are made in order it would be easier to notice changes. They work like right/left swipe. Native swipes give the same result.

The code is this one:

```
var currentIndexPath: IndexPath = [0,0]

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    
            var testIndexPath = indexPath
            cell.imageView.image = allPhotos[testIndexPath.item].faceCard
           
            return cell
        }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
           currentIndexPath = indexPath
       }

label.text = "\(currentIndexPath)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override **scrollViewDidScroll** method and get the visible cell's indexPath when swiped:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: collectionView.contentOffset, size: collectionView.bounds.size)
    let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
    if let testIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint) {
        label.text = "testIndexPath: \(testIndexPath)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use collectionview.indexPathForVisibleItems to get the indexPath when collectionView end scroll.

you can check collectionView end scroll by this:
[Swift 4 UICollectionView detect end of scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705430/swift-4-uicollectionview-detect-end-of-scrolling)